why am I getting a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently response from github pages instead of HTTP/1.1 200 OK
I have a site hosted on github pages from which I share some pages to facebook.
Everything has been fine until today when all of a sudden the images that were supposed to appear when sharing a link (URL) didn't appear. So, I'm trying to get to the root cause of this.
I've tested the URL's in facebook's 'sharing debugger' tool that I normally use to resolve such problems with.
Now I'm getting a

Bad Response Code:
URL returned a bad HTTP response code:
Response Code 403

instead of 'Response Code 200 OK'
This appears to be all pages including those that were previously OK.
So, I ran a cURL command to see what that showed:
C:\Users\owner>curl -I nuttyskitchen.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 162
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://www.nuttyskitchen.co.uk/
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 2D99:185178:589C03:59F3D4:66D1E682
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2024 15:34:27 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Served-By: cache-ams2100087-AMS
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1725032067.025061,VS0,VE103
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Fastly-Request-ID: 7fa3d6e4e6e2f3f8ddf54a373998275196ceecc1

and then did the same for example.com to make a comparrison:
C:\Users\owner>curl -I example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 484008
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2024 16:56:48 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+gzip"
Expires: Fri, 06 Sep 2024 16:56:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECAcc (nyd/D17F)
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256

and I can see that from the first cURL command I have HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently whereas on the second run for example.com I have HTTP/1.1 200 OK which is what I was expecting to see from nuttyskitchen.co.uk.
Has anyone any experience of this happening specifically on a site hosted on github pages and/or how if anything I can do to resolve it?
I'm really stuck so would be very thankful of any help you can give.
Thanks in advance :¬)

It is not uncommon for sites to redirect when they want to tweak the URL (ie hostname -> hostname/), or change protocols (ie http: -> https:), or add cookies, etc. This is certainly not limited to just GitHub. Do you have the same redirect if you ask curl to get https://nuttyskitchen.co.uk/ directly?

no I get this response: C:\Users\owner>curl https://nuttyskitchen.co.uk curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

& FWIW today I'm getting a http response of 206 in facebook's sharing debugger. I don't know if this a facebook problem or github pages server.

Regarding the schannel error, try adding the -k option to skip certificate validation. Regarding the 206 response, that should only happen if a ranged request (ie the Range request header) was sent to download only a portion of a file

Yeah! Thank for that, finally I have a decent response 200 OK using curl. Still getting that 206 response in facebooks tool though. Surely that can only be facebook making a range request and not the github server having a wobbly?
